# How to determine if all set bits in one number is also set in another number?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Given 2 binary strings `a` and `b` of the same length (e.g. `111000` and `110000`), is it possible to check if all set bits in `b` is also set in `a` using bitwise operations? In the above example, `b = 110000` has two set bits in position 1 and 2 (from left to right), and those bits are also set in `a = 111000`.

I can compare two strings character-wise but that would be too slow. I know I can turn the strings into number with something like `Integer.parseInt(a, 2);` but I don't know the bitwise operations to use to achieve the task.

Comment: I want to upvote for being clear and specific and downvote for asking such an easily researched question.

Comment: Why is comparing character by character too slow? Sure it has to loop over the thing, but then so does parsing them to integers..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mask the bits and then check if they're still all set.

```
int a = 0b111000;
int b = 0b110000;

if ((a & b) == b) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: OP's input is strings, not numbers, so your answer should cover the parsing as well. You should cover very large "binary strings" as well, i.e. 65+ bits *(hint: `BigInteger`)*.

Comment: You can write that answer if you want. The OP already knows how to turn strings into numbers, and 65+ bit numbers are a rarity.

Comment: @Andreas He should have actually flagged this as a duplicate in the same fashion `NullPointerException` questions are flagged. "*I know I can turn the strings into number with something like Integer.parseInt(a, 2); **but I don't know the bitwise operations to use to achieve the task.***" where this information has already been covered in many other Q&As here. Rather than encourage research, the OP was spoonfed, which kills me to see coming from someone with 100k+ reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the characters:

```
for (int pos = 0; (pos = b.indexOf('1', pos)) != -1; ++pos) {
  if (a.charAt(pos) != '1') {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

`b.indexOf('1', pos)` will find the next `1` in `b` starting from position `pos`; simply check if the corresponding character in `a` is also `1`.