# Check if bits of an integers are contained in another one

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Here is a question I coudl'nt find an answer for.
This is for python but it could apply to other languages.
Assume I have these integers with binary representation

```
a  = 000101
b1 = 001111
b2 = 001110
```

I want a check that checks if the bits set in a are also all set in b
For instance, this is the case with a and b1. But not the case with a and b2, because the last bit is set in a and not set in b2.
I guess it can be done by checking all bits one by one, but I'm assuming there is a trick to it in fewer operations when my integers are 32 bits

Comment: The bitwise and operation `&`?

Comment: Perhaps using bitwise and i.e. `if a & v == a` then v has all of a's bit set.

Comment: @ThomasWeller eh I dimissed this because it was symetrical, but indeed that should do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if all set bits in one number is also set in another number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927391/how-to-determine-if-all-set-bits-in-one-number-is-also-set-in-another-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bitwise and](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) operation does what you need:

```
a = 0b000101
b1 = 0b001111
b2 = 0b001110
if a & b1 == a: print("a is in b1")
if a & b2 == a: print("a is in b2")
```